# Making small caps in Word 2016 for Mac

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2016

How do I make small caps in Microsoft Word 2016 for Mac? The keyboard shortcut isn't working and the option no longer appears on the tool bar

Comment: Have you tried to add it to the toolbar?  You do the same way you add any default but "hidden" option to the toolbar

Comment: Workaround: add small-caps font, such as those at http://www.1001fonts.com/small-caps-fonts.html

Comment: FWIW the keyboard shortcut works OK here. Does the font have Small caps glyphs? AFAIK there is currently no way to modify the toolbars on this version of Word. You can check that the key is assigned by going into Tools->CustomizeKeyboard, selecting category Format, and searching for SmallCaps. If Command+Shift+K is not there, it may have been assigned to something else. If it is there, then it may have been assigned to something in the Mac operating system. You can add your own keyboard shortcut there (e.g. Command+Option+Shift+K is "available" here. Make sure you click Assign.

Answer (score 1):

1. Highlight the text where you want the Small Caps
2. Right-click the mouse
3. Select "Font" from drop down
4. Select "Small Caps" and OK